# JBoss https on port other than 8080 not working

Tags: java, ssl, https, jboss

We have a server with two JBoss instances where one runs on 8080, the other on 8081. We need to have HTTPS enabled for the 8081 server, firstly we tried enabling https on the 8080 port instance by generating the keystore and editing the `server.xml` and it successfully worked. However when we tried the same thing for 8081 it did not, note that we removed https for the 8080 server first before enabling it for 8081.

This is what was used for both `server.xml` for 8080 and 8081. The only difference was that the port was changed from 8080 to 8081 when trying to enable https for 8081 port instance. What am I doing wrong and what needs to be changed?

NOTE : When I meant enabled for 8080 I meant when you visit https:// URL:8484 you will actually be visiting the 8080 port instance. However when ssl is enabled for 8081 and I visit https:// URL:8484 I get that the web page is unavailable.

*COMMENTLESS VERSION*

```
    <Server>

 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />

   <Service name="jboss.web">
   <!-- https -->
    <Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
         maxThreads="350" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
         emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
         connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" compression="on" ompressableMimeType="text/html,text/css,text/javascript,application/json,text/xml,text/plain,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
                keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/supun1.keystore"
                keystorePass="aaaaaa"
                truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/supun1.keystore"
                truststorePass="aaaaaa" />

    <!-- https1 -->

    <Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3"
         emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" />

      <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="khms1">

         <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
            certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
            allRolesMode="authOnly"
            />
        <Host name="localhost"
           autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false"
           configClass="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.config.JBossContextConfig"
           >
            <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.sso.ClusteredSingleSignOn" />

            <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"
                cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"
                transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" />

         </Host>

      </Engine>

   </Service>

</Server>
```

*WITH COMMENTS VERSION*

```
    <Server>

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />

   <!-- Use a custom version of StandardService that allows the
   connectors to be started independent of the normal lifecycle
   start to allow web apps to be deployed before starting the
   connectors.
   -->
   <Service name="jboss.web">

    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
         maxThreads="350" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
         emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
         connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" compression="on" ompressableMimeType="text/html,text/css,text/javascript,application/json,text/xml,text/plain,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>

    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/zara.keystore"  keystorePass="zara2010" 
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" compression="on" />
    -->
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
                keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/supun1.keystore"
                keystorePass="aaaaaa"
                truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/supun1.keystore"
                truststorePass="aaaaaa" />


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3"
         emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" />

      <Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="khms1">

         <!-- The JAAS based authentication and authorization realm implementation
         that is compatible with the jboss 3.2.x realm implementation.
         - certificatePrincipal : the class name of the
         org.jboss.security.auth.certs.CertificatePrincipal impl
         used for mapping X509[] cert chains to a Princpal.
         - allRolesMode : how to handle an auth-constraint with a role-name=*,
         one of strict, authOnly, strictAuthOnly
           + strict = Use the strict servlet spec interpretation which requires
           that the user have one of the web-app/security-role/role-name
           + authOnly = Allow any authenticated user
           + strictAuthOnly = Allow any authenticated user only if there are no
           web-app/security-roles
         -->
         <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JBossSecurityMgrRealm"
            certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
            allRolesMode="authOnly"
            />
         <!-- A subclass of JBossSecurityMgrRealm that uses the authentication
         behavior of JBossSecurityMgrRealm, but overrides the authorization
         checks to use JACC permissions with the current java.security.Policy
         to determine authorized access.
         - allRolesMode : how to handle an auth-constraint with a role-name=*,
         one of strict, authOnly, strictAuthOnly
           + strict = Use the strict servlet spec interpretation which requires
           that the user have one of the web-app/security-role/role-name
           + authOnly = Allow any authenticated user
           + strictAuthOnly = Allow any authenticated user only if there are no
           web-app/security-roles
         <Realm className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccAuthorizationRealm"
            certificatePrincipal="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.SubjectDNMapping"
            allRolesMode="authOnly"
            />
         -->

        <Host name="localhost"
           autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false"
           configClass="org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.config.JBossContextConfig"
           >

            <!-- Uncomment to enable request dumper. This Valve "logs interesting 
                 contents from the specified Request (before processing) and the 
                 corresponding Response (after processing). It is especially useful 
                 in debugging problems related to headers and cookies."
            -->

<!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve" />
    -->        

            <!-- Access logger -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
                pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" 
                resolveHosts="false" />
            -->

            <!-- Uncomment to enable single sign-on across web apps
                deployed to this host. Does not provide SSO across a cluster.     

                If this valve is used, do not use the JBoss ClusteredSingleSignOn 
                valve shown below. 

                A new configuration attribute is available beginning with
                release 4.0.4:

                cookieDomain  configures the domain to which the SSO cookie
                              will be scoped (i.e. the set of hosts to
                              which the cookie will be presented).  By default
                              the cookie is scoped to "/", meaning the host
                              that presented it.  Set cookieDomain to a
                              wider domain (e.g. "xyz.com") to allow an SSO
                              to span more than one hostname.
             -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
            -->

            <!-- Uncomment to enable single sign-on across web apps
               deployed to this host AND to all other hosts in the cluster.

               If this valve is used, do not use the standard Tomcat SingleSignOn
               valve shown above.

               Valve uses a JBossCache instance to support SSO credential 
               caching and replication across the cluster.  The JBossCache 
               instance must be configured separately.  By default, the valve 
               shares a JBossCache with the service that supports HttpSession 
               replication.  See the "jboss-web-cluster-service.xml" file in the 
               server/all/deploy directory for cache configuration details.

               Besides the attributes supported by the standard Tomcat
               SingleSignOn valve (see the Tomcat docs), this version also 
               supports the following attributes:

               cookieDomain   see above

               treeCacheName  JMX ObjectName of the JBossCache MBean used to 
                              support credential caching and replication across
                              the cluster. If not set, the default value is 
                              "jboss.cache:service=TomcatClusteringCache", the 
                              standard ObjectName of the JBossCache MBean used 
                              to support session replication.
            -->

            <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.sso.ClusteredSingleSignOn" />


            <!-- Check for unclosed connections and transaction terminated checks
                 in servlets/jsps.

                 Important: The dependency on the CachedConnectionManager
                 in META-INF/jboss-service.xml must be uncommented, too
            -->
            <Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"
                cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"
                transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" />

         </Host>

      </Engine>

   </Service>

</Server>
```

Comment: Nothing in your configuration suggests that HTTPS is enabled on port 8080: it's enabled on port 8443.

Comment: When I meant enabled for 8080 I meant when you visit https:// URL:8484 you will actually be visiting the 8080 port instance. However when ssl is enabled for 8081 and I visit https:// URL:8484 I get that the web page is unavailable.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. When you visit :8484 you are visiting :8484, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these servers on the same machine? I think problem is that if you run the servers on same machine, you only change 8080 port to 8081, but JBoss server opens more than this one port. My assumption is that second server fails to open some other ports and start incorrectly. When changing server ports it's recommended to use port binding set, which will change all ports.

This starting parameter should be used:

```
-Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
```

But you won't have 8081 port but 8180 and all ports will be raised by 100.